# Best practice for importing a partial database dump into a rails app daily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3, itunes-store

The [iTunes Enterprise Partner Feed](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed.html) is "a data feed of the complete set of metadata from iTunes and the App Store" and "is available in two different formats - either as the files necessary to build a relational database or as stand-alone flat files that are country and media dependent."

I need to consume the data from this feed (which is essentially exported into flat files) and allow linking of my own Model objects (User, Activity, etc.) to data provided by the feed (App, Developer, etc.) The data is provided as a weekly full export **and** a daily incremental export.

I have two ideas for ways to implement this:

1. Create all of the models in my rails app and write my own importer that will insert/update records directly into my app's database daily via cron using models I've created (App, Developer, etc.)
2. Keep this database entirely separate and open up REST API that my own app will consume

My naive approach with **#1** to keep everything in the Rails app is based on the need to be able to observe changes in the data I'm getting from the EPF. For example, if an App's description is updated, I want to be able to create an Activity object via an observer to track that update.

On one hand **#2** feels like a better approach because it creates a standalone API into the data that can be consumed from several different apps I create. On the other hand, I'm just not sure how I'd accomplish the data change notifications without using observers directly on my own models. Or, how I would even consume the data in an object oriented way that could still be used with my own models. It feels like a lot of duplicate work to have to query the API for, say, an App's data, create a proper Active Record object for it and then save it just so it can be linked to one of my own models.

Is there a standard way to do this that I'm totally missing? Any pointers?

**EDIT:** Rails engines sound interesting but it would mean that each app would still need to consume and insert the data separately. That doesn't sound so DRY. It sounds more and more like a REST API is the way to go. I just don't know how to bridge the gap from API to Active Record model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails Engines might be a good fit for this.  You can create a Rails Engine gem and add all of your models and rake tasks to consume the data.  Then you can include this gem in any app that uses it and also create an API app which includes the gem.  You should be able to create observers in your other apps that interact with the gem.

I have quite a few apps that interact with each other and this approach works well for me.  I have one *central* app that includes all the engines that consume data and I run all of my cronjobs from this app.  I use the `use_db` plugin which allows my app to communicate with different databases.  Each engine has `use_db` as a dependency and I keep the database configuration inside the gem. One example:

1. Engine Gem = transaction_core
2. This gem consumes transaction data from a source and inserts it into my transaction database.
3. The gem is included in my *central* app and I pull the transaction data using a rake task on the cron
4. I include this gem in several other apps that need to use the transaction data.  Since the engine automatically adds the models and database config to the app, there is no additional work required to use the models in the app.

I have not used observers inside an app that includes my engines, but I see no reason why it would not work.  With the engine the models work as if they are in your app/models directory.  Hope this helps!

Modest Rubyist has a good 4 part tutorial on Rails 3 plugins that includes Engines:
http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/03/05/rails-3-plugins---part-2---writing-an-engine/

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is what I'm looking for, but it's really the first I've heard of rails engines. I'll try to take a deeper look at them. Thanks.

Comment: Engines are probably my favorite feature of Rails 3.  They are basically just mini rails apps that you can include in other apps with a gem.  This approach would be like #1, but you could use it in multiple apps (like #2) as long as you are using a plugin that can handle different database connections per model.

Comment: you might use existing gem to do imports https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db